# How do we make UI Design suggestion for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, design

How do we make UI Design suggestion for Stack Overflow?

Comment: It feels awkward asking a question when I'm trying to make a suggestion. It feels like Jeopardy.

Comment: It has to be this way, on SO you can question a question, question an answer or even answer a question - but you can't answer an answer.

Comment: Meta sites are a little different than the regular SE sites. Making a suggestion here is perfectly fine, you don't have to phrase it in the form of a question. Just take a look at the other feature requests on the site.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to phrase it as a question here, if you're making a feature request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post your suggestion here on Meta and tag it with feature-request.

Include any details, why you think it should be changed, mock-ups, etc. Anything you think might help your case.

Answer (score 3):

When adding mock-ups be sure to use hand-drawn red circles to highlight changed areas - and if possible incorporate a unicorn or two in the design.

Answer (score 0):

You're at the right place. Put a question about Design UI suggestions, preferably with mocks-ups and you're good to go.